# Read an org.jdom.Document object with groovy

Tags: xml, groovy, jdom

I have an org.jdom.Document object that I'd like to process using groovy XMLSlurper.

I am currently using the following code:

```
// doc is my org.jdom.Document object
new XMLSlurper().parseText(new XMLOutputter().outputString(doc));
```

The conversion from Document to String takes some time. Is there any better alternative to avoid the conversion in order to speedup the execution?

Comment: all `parse.*` methods only take some sort of file,stream,string http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/util/XmlSlurper.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert JDOM into an intermediate form that Groovy XML API supports. Convert from JDOM into a string which you can then parse with [XmlSlurper](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/XmlSlurper.html).

```
// doc is org.jdom.Document object
def xo = new org.jdom2.output.XMLOutputter()
String xmlContent = xo.outputString(doc)
```

Now JDOM doc is in a string representation to parse with Groovy XmlSlurper or XmlParser.

```
def rootNode = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xmlContent)
println groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize(rootNode)
```